# Capital aware position sizing in quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am looking to make maximum allowed position for a particular asset(symbol) a function of capital(initial allocation+ PL), and indicators. I tried going through replacing `osMaxPos`. I add this at the top, where initial value is hardcoded, and ddQ is my indicator,

```
updatePortf(portfolio, symbol, Dates=paste('::',as.Date(timestamp),sep=''))
cumPL <- sum(getPortfolio(portfolio)$symbols[[symbol]]$posPL$Net.Trading.PL)
print(paste0("expFluct", data$ddQ[timestamp]*2))
maxPosVal <- (10e6+cumPL) * data$ddQ[timestamp]*2
print(paste0("maxPosVal = ", maxPosVal))
addPosLimit(portfolio, 
          symbol=symbol, 
          timestamp = first(index(data)),
          maxpos = maxPosVal
)
```

This works but takes the execution of an intraday strategy with about 2 years of 1 min data from minutes to hours as my portfolio is being marked on every call. Can someone point out a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a rebalancing rule instead, like `rulePctEquity`.

See

`demo('macdRebalancing')`

for an example.

Most real portfolios would not be rebalanced on every trade, since that's not particularly practical, especially on intraday data.

`rulePctEquity` does call `updatePortf`, but you'll get usually very little value in practice from adjusting your trade size on every new observation.

It differs from your example by marking the whole portfolio, and looking at total equity, not just accumulated P&L in one instrument.

If you want to adjust more frequently, or want to adjust just based on P&L in a single instrument, then you don't need `updatePortf` at all. If you want only your initial allocation plus P&L in a single instrument, then you should sum the realized P&L for that instrument from the `Txns` table, and calculate an unrealized P&L from the difference in your open position and the current market price.  This will be several hundreds of times faster than calls to `updatePortf` in most cases.